# Unique bounded function satisfying $f(s)=1+\int_{0}^{s} e^{-t^{2}} f(s t) d t$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Prove that there is a unique bounded continuous real valued function $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f(s)=1+\int_{0}^{s} e^{-t^{2}} f(s t) d t
$$
for all $s \in[0, \infty)$

First as far as I searched $C[0,\infty)\cap B[0,\infty) $ is complete under sup metric.

So I tried to use [Banach Fixed Point Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)

similar to here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1350747/342943

But I was confused about using the bound, which is not similar in the above question. $e^{-t^2}$ is going to overcome $f(t)$ for sufficiently bigger $n$.

Can you give me hint?

Or is there another approach that I can show above $f$ is unique and existent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Banach fixed-point theorem can be used. As pointed out in the comments to [On the solution of a Volterra type of integral equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070729/on-the-solution-of-a-volterra-type-of-integral-equation), $T: C[0,\infty) \to C[0,\infty)$ defined by
$$ 
Tf(s)= 1+ \int_{0}^s e^{-t^2} f(st)dt
$$
maps bounded functions to bounded functions:
$$
|Tf(s)| \le 1 + \int_{0}^s e^{-t^2} \, dt \cdot \Vert f \Vert_\infty \\
\le 1 + \int_{0}^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt \cdot \Vert f \Vert_\infty = 1 + \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2 } \Vert f \Vert_\infty
$$
and is a contraction:
$$
|Tf(s) - Tg(s)| \le  \int_0^s e^{-t^2} \, dt \cdot \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty \\
\le  \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt \cdot \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty 
= \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2 }\cdot \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty 
$$
because $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2 } \approx 0.886 < 1$.

For the value of $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt $ see for example [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2).